# Expand div outside container - overflow-x mobile issue

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Recently i tried [this method](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/full-width-bars/index.html)  to increase my div background-color outside its container.Everything is ok except that applying the overflow-x to body ,on mobile browsers is not really working.I mean when you swipe to the left is still scrolling ( same effect you can achieve it on desktop if you press right arrow on your keyboard ) .So how can we completely disable scrolling horizontally on mobiles when using this method?

Here my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kzgvL6ba/

Here's my example:
HTML:

```
<body>
    <article>
        <div class="extendfull">Full-width Bars</div>
    </article>
</body>
```

css:

```
body
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
article {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 60%;
}
div.extendfull {
    background-color: #ccf;
    border: 1px solid #66c;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 3000px;
    margin-left: -3000px;
    padding-right: 3000px;
    margin-right: -3000px;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the solution you're looking for, but add another container to remove the scroll right and to have the same result (I think...)

```
<body>
    <div style="overflow-x: hidden">
        <article>
            <div class="extendfull">Full-width Bars</div>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzgvL6ba/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Will this disable the zoom? If so is not what i'm looking for.Thanks.